# Add JButtons to JTable cell + DB

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I have a JTable, I want to populate this JTable from a database.
The first mission is done.

The second mission is how to add JButton in this JTable, I have acolumn that I must put a button in, the number of buttons change with the number of rows.

How can I do??

This is an example in the image:
[image]

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.
Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) should help you out.

Comment: Im having trouble creating one of these. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I did give you an example. I showed you how to create a simple action. It is then one line of code to have a column of text be rendered as a button.